# ViewPager stealing Horizontal Touch Events from Child Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I have a `ViewPager`, the `ViewPager` contains two tabs, each tab contains a `RecyclerView`, cards can be added and removed from each `RecyclerView`. Each `RecyclerView` is contained within a `Fragment`. Each `RecyclerView`uses an `ItemTouchHelper` to manage `onSwiped()` events. Cards within in the `RecyclerView` have several behaviors:

- Swiping to the right opens an editor for the card
- Swiping to the left deletes the Card
- Holding down on the card and dragging vertically up or down re-positions the card.

My problem is that the `ViewPager` is intercepting the `onSwiped()` method for each `RecyclerView`, however, vertical touch events are still recieved properly by each `RecyclerView`. Obviously, this boils down to a touch conflict problem. The `ViewPager` wants the horizontal touch events for changing tabs, and the `RecyclerView` wants the horizontal touch events for swiping the cards. However, the `ViewPager` is stealing all of the touch events. I have disabled horizontal swiping on the `ViewPager` (the only way the user can change the tab is by tapping on the tab indicator), but the `RecyclerView` still won't receive any horizontal touch events.

Here's the `ViewPager` with disabled swiping:

```
public class NoSwipePager extends ViewPager {

public NoSwipePager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Here's a Fragment class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pit_tab, container, false);
    container.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_recycler_view);

    return view;
}
```

Here is the class that manages the `RecyclerView`:

```
    public EditManager(RecyclerView rv, Context act, EditListener listener, ArrayList<Element> elements, boolean editing, boolean pit) {
    //rv = (RecyclerView) act.findViewById(R.id.movie_recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(act);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    ((SimpleItemAnimator) rv.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);

    if(elements != null) elementsAdapter = new ElementsAdapter(listener, act, new LinkedList<>(elements), editing);
    else elementsAdapter = new ElementsAdapter(listener, act, null, editing);
    rv.setAdapter(elementsAdapter);

    ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new ElementTouchHelper(elementsAdapter);
    ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
    helper.attachToRecyclerView(rv);
}
```

And finally, here's the method that should be being called, but isn't:

```
    @Override
public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    if(direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        mElementsAdapter.postEdit(mElementsAdapter.getElement(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your `NoSwipePager` with this:

```
public class NoSwipePager extends ViewPager {
  public NoSwipePager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x,
                              int y) {
    if (v instanceof RecyclerView) {
      return(true);
    }

    return(super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y));
  }
}
```

I have used this approach successfully for a `ViewPager` with maps in the pages (substituting `SurfaceView` for the `RecyclerView`). My guess is that you will need to replace the `v instanceof RecyclerView` test with something more sophisticated (and custom to your app). But I think `canScroll()` is more likely to give you what you want than blocking `onInterceptTouchEvent()`.

Comment: Okay, so I replaced the `ViewPager` with your code but it still doesn't work. Swiping to change tabs works now if the swipe starts near the edges of the screen, but the cards within the `RecyclerView` still don't move. Any other ideas? @CommonsWare

Comment: @wdavies973: What did you wind up using in your `if()` test, where I have `v instanceof RecyclerView`?

Comment: Well, currently it's just the same (`v instanceof RecyclerView`) but I don't think `canScroll()` makes a difference on the `RecylerViews` receiving `onSwiped()`, do you have any suggestions? I could check for View ID, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Vertical scrolling still works fine on the `RecyclerView`, it's the left and right swiping of cards that doesn't work. @CommonsWare

Comment: @wdavies973: Add `|| v instanceof CardView` (or whatever your cards are) and see what happens. Basically, you want `canScroll()` to return `true` for any widget that you want to have do its own scrolling/swiping, `false` otherwise.

Comment: It has the same behavior as last time, however it does seem like any swipes that occur within the `RecyclerView` area are not processed by the `ViewPager`, so I think it's just an issue of getting the scrolling in the `RecylerView` to end up in the `ItemTouchHelper onSwiped()` method

Comment: @wdavies973: Yeah, I don't know how to do that. If you have not done so already, you might try temporarily using that `RecyclerView` and contents outside the `ViewPager` itself. Get your desired behavior working, then re-introduce the `RecyclerView` into the `ViewPager`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138433/discussion-between-wdavies973-and-commonsware).